# Bootstrap Column CSS

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here is my Angular2 Form

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" autocomplete="off" novalidate>         <div 
class="row">    <div class="form-group col-md-4" [ngClass]="{    'error' : 
myForm.controls.firstname.invalid &&        
myForm.controls.firstname.touched}">
<label for="firstname">Please tell us your name</label>
<control-messages [control]="myForm.controls.firstname"></control-messages>
<input  name="firstname"  formControlName="firstname" type="text" 
class="form-control" placeholder="First Name *" />       </div>    <div 
class="form-group col-md-4" >
<label for="middlename">&nbsp; </label>
<control-messages [control]="myForm.controls.middlename"></control-messages>
<input  name="middlename" id="middlename" type="text" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Middle Name"       formControlName="middlename"/>    </div>    
<div class="form-group    col-md-4" [ngClass]="{ 'error' : 
myForm.controls.lastname.invalid &&     myForm.controls.lastname.touched    
}">
<label for="lastname"> &nbsp;</label>
<control-messages [control]="myForm.controls.lastname"></control-messages>
<input name="lastname"  formControlName="lastname" type="text" class="form-
control" placeholder="Last Name *"/>    </div>   </div>   
</form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WPzF.png)

How do I line up all the columns correctly? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form [formGroup]="myForm" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4" [ngClass]="{    'error' :
         myForm.controls.firstname.invalid &&
         myForm.controls.firstname.touched}">
      <label for="firstname">Please tell us your name</label>
      <control-messages [control]="myForm.controls.firstname"></control-messages>
      <input name="firstname" formControlName="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name *" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="middlename">&nbsp; </label>
      <control-messages [control]="myForm.controls.middlename"></control-messages>
      <input name="middlename" id="middlename" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle Name" formControlName="middlename" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4" [ngClass]="{ 'error' :
         myForm.controls.lastname.invalid && myForm.controls.lastname.touched
         }">
      <label for="lastname"> &nbsp;</label>
      <control-messages [control]="myForm.controls.lastname"></control-messages>
      <input name="lastname" formControlName="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name *" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

You had some line breaks in between `form-control` for the last name input field, try like this:

```
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4" [ngClass]="{    'error' :
         myForm.controls.firstname.invalid &&
         myForm.controls.firstname.touched}">
         <label for="firstname">Please tell us your name</label>
         <control-messages [control]="myForm.controls.firstname"></control-messages>
         <input name="firstname"  formControlName="firstname" type="text"
            class="form-control" placeholder="First Name *" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4" >
         <label for="middlename">&nbsp; </label>
         <control-messages [control]="myForm.controls.middlename"></control-messages>
         <input name="middlename" id="middlename" type="text" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Middle Name"       formControlName="middlename"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4" [ngClass]="{ 'error' :
         myForm.controls.lastname.invalid && myForm.controls.lastname.touched
         }">
         <label for="lastname"> &nbsp;</label>
         <control-messages [control]="myForm.controls.lastname"></control-messages>
         <input name="lastname"  formControlName="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name *"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Cyber. But it didn't help.